# Converting nd2 image to color png

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I use this code to get from a nd2 file two images (from each channel).
Currently the image is black and white with an enhanced contrast

```
from nd2reader import ND2Reader
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance
import sys, getopt, os

argv = sys.argv[1:]

def saveImage(imageData, path):
  im = Image.fromarray(imageData)
  im.mode = 'I'
  convertedImage = im.point(lambda i: i * (1. / 256)).convert('L')

  contrastEnhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(convertedImage)

  im_output = contrastEnhancer.enhance(10)
  im_output.save(path, "PNG")


def convertImage(inputFile):

  fileName = os.path.splitext(inputFile)[0]

  with ND2Reader(inputFile) as images:
    greenFrame = images.get_frame(0)
    redFrame = images.get_frame(1)

    saveImage(greenFrame, fileName + "_green.png")
    saveImage(redFrame, fileName + "_red.png")


def main(argv):
  inputfile = ''

  try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "hi:", ["ifile="])
  except getopt.GetoptError:
    print('test.py -i <inputfile>')
    sys.exit(2)

  if(len(opts) < 1):
    print('test.py -i <inputfile>')
    sys.exit(2)

  for opt, arg in opts:
    if opt == '-h':
      print ('test.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>')
      sys.exit()
    elif opt in ("-i", "--ifile"):
      inputfile = arg

  convertImage(inputfile)


main(argv)
```

I'm having trouble getting a color image... The Image in the nd2 is either green or red. And i would like to have it in the final png as well with the full color.

I tried multiple things. Of course removing the convert('L'), changeing the im.mode to RGB or add mode=RGB to the fromarray method.

i got different error messages like `ValueError: image has wrong mode` or the image in the end is just black.

Does somebody have an idea where the problem might be?
Thank you very much!